# Mongoose save function doesn't return me the saved record - pending

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have the following function which should create a new user. Everything works really well so far, at least locally. But as soon as I host the whole thing on Vercel and link it to my frontend, I get a pending message in the debugger. After a while, either a 500 when I use res.status(200).json(savedUser) or a pending res.status(200).send(savedUser). No matter how rum, the saved user is not returned. If I send a simple string, everything works.

```
/CREATE NEW USER
export const newUser = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
 const user = new User({ ...req.body.user });

 const savedUser = await user.save();
 res.status(200).json(savedUser);

 } catch (error) {
   res.status(404).send("error");
 }
};
```

Comment: Are there any logs of the server? Show the full error stack, you need to debug why there is an internal server error. We can't help without debugging details.